# React Native CodePush update issue

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-code-push

I have configured react-native-codepush in my react-native project.

When i release an update in the appcenter I can see the release history but after the release when I reopen the app for the first time I could not see any update but when I reopen the app for the second time then I am able to see the updates.

Can anyone please help me as to why the app is not getting updated when I open the app for the first time after release the update.

I have added below code check.

```
const codePushOptions = {
 checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_START,
 installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE
};

export default codePush(codePushOptions)(App);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find solution??

Comment: yes i was able to,

Comment: @Shariq how did you resolve it ?